# Use javascript in Perl CGI

Tags: javascript, perl, cgi, wamp

i am trying to run javascript in a perl CGI file. The code is as follows

```
#!C:\wamp\bin\perl\bin\perl.exe

$html = "Content-Type: text/html

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Hello World</TITLE>
<SCRIPT TYPE="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT">
alert("i am here");
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H4>Hello World</H4>
<P>
Your IP Address is $ENV{REMOTE_ADDR}
<P>
<H5>Have a nice day</H5>
</BODY>
</HTML>";

print $html;
```

I am getting an internal server error.

The code with just the html works fine
Please let me know what has to be done to include javascript in Perl

Answer (score 6):

You can't use double quotes inside your double-quoted string without escaping them.  The internal server error is caused by Perl trying to tell you that

```
$html = "..."TEXT/JAVASCRIPT"..."i am here"...";
```

is not valid Perl code.  If you check your server's error log, you'll see something like "Bareword found where operator expected at...".

The simpler solution is to use a [here document](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%3C%3CEOF):

```
#!C:\wamp\bin\perl\bin\perl.exe

use strict;
use warnings;

my $html = <<"END HTML";
Content-Type: text/html

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Hello World</TITLE>
<SCRIPT TYPE="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT">
alert("i am here");
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H4>Hello World</H4>
<P>
Your IP Address is $ENV{REMOTE_ADDR}
<P>
<H5>Have a nice day</H5>
</BODY>
</HTML>
END HTML

print $html;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `qq()` when outputing HTML or JavaScript.

```
#!C:\wamp\bin\perl\bin\perl.exe
use warnings;
use strict;

my $html = qq(Content-Type: text/html

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Hello World</TITLE>
<SCRIPT TYPE="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT">
alert("i am here");
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H4>Hello World</H4>
<P>
Your IP Address is $ENV{REMOTE_ADDR}
<P>
<H5>Have a nice day</H5>
</BODY>
</HTML>);

print $html;
```

You can use `{}` instead of `()` as delimiters. see the [document](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators).

> a {} represents any pair of delimiters you choose.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out the problem is the erroneous quoting.

As a small tip (besides fixing the quoting as mentioned above)

Add

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

to the top of your script, so you can always check the syntax by executing `perl -c`

in your case:

```
C:\wamp\bin\perl\bin\perl.exe -c <filename>
```

this would have shown you the error immidiately.

HTH Georg